# Proving this pointwise limit via definition

Tags: pointwise-convergence

For 
$f_n(x) = \frac{nx + x^2}{n^2}$, this converges pointwise to the function $f(x) = 0$.
How would I prove this formally?
This is my attempt:
$$|f_n(x) - f(x)| = |\frac{nx + x^2}{n^2}| \leq |\frac{nx + nx^2}{n^2}| = |\frac{x + x^2}{n}|$$
So if I were to pick $N := \frac{|x + x^2|}{\epsilon}$ then by reversing the steps, we get the required inequality.
My question is: Is my choice of $N$ correct (is there allowance for the absolute values)? And if so, just to confirm for pointwise convergence, the allowance of having $x$ terms in the value for $N$ is O.K. right?

Comment: "is there allowance for the absolute values": provided you find a suitable value of $N$ for any $\epsilon$, any expression is "allowed".

Comment: Thanks, the main reason why I asked that is because in other epsilon delta proofs, I would always try to find a way to get rid of absolute values, but I didn't know why.

Answer (score 1):

First, $N$ has to be an integer number.

Second, what you wrote $$|f_n(x) - f(x)| = |\frac{nx + x^2}{n^2}| \leq |\frac{nx + nx^2}{n^2}| = |\frac{x + x^2}{n}|$$

is incorrect the middle inequality does not hold necessarly !
For example: if $x=-1$ The RHS is zero, LHS is always positive for all $n \ge2.$

Comment: I see, so the absolute values do not matter?  in an epsilon proof?

Comment: Regardingyour edit:  
That's weird, because I thought $nx + nx^2 \geq nx + x^2$ for all $n \geq 1$, so I'm not sure why this doesn't cover that $x=1$ case.

Comment: $nx + nx^2 \geq nx + x^2$ is true, only for all $x >0$

Comment: Hmm, but if I have $n \geq 1 \iff n-1 \geq 0 \iff x^2(n-1) \geq 0 \iff nx^2 \geq x^2 \iff nx + nx^2 \geq nx +x^2$

Answer (score 1):

Why did you stop? :) From where you stopped, note that $N:= \lfloor \frac{|x+x^{2}|}{\varepsilon} \rfloor  + 1 > \frac{|x+x^{2}|}{\varepsilon}$ and is an integer for sure.

Comment: Thanks! So absolute value signs do not matter right? Iirc, in other epsilon delta proofs like just the limit of a function to a value, I remember always trying to find ways to remove absolute value signs, but I wasn't always sure why

Comment: You only have to make sure $N$ is an integer; the absolute value thing does not matter here.

Answer (score 1):

We may establish

$$\left|\frac{nx+x^2}{n^2}\right|<\left|\frac{x}{n}\right|+\left|\frac{x^2}{n^2}\right|<\epsilon.$$

An easy option is to make both terms smaller than $\epsilon/2$, which is achieved by

$$n>\left|\frac{2x}{\epsilon}\right|\text{ and }n>\sqrt{\left|\frac{2x^2}{\epsilon}\right|}$$ and we can take the maximum of the two.

Comment: Cheers! I forgot about the maxmum function for some reason.